# a question in projection

Tags: hilbert-spaces, approximation, inner-products

Let $V=L^2(\Omega)$, and
$$k=\{v \in V ~s.t ~||v||_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq 1 \}$$
I need to find projection  for any $u \in V$ on $k$.

Please help me.I do not have any idea about this problem. I have many theorem about exisitence and uniqueness solution, but I do not know how to find it.

Thanks.

Comment: What about $\frac{u}{\|u\|}$? When $\|u\|\geq 1$, of course. It is $u$ otherwise.

Comment: Since $L^2(\Omega)$ is Hilbert space, it has an inner product. How would you find the projection with inner product?

Comment: And it is worth noticing that $k$ is not a subspace, instead simply a subset of $V$.

Comment: @newbie Not simply a subset. A closed convex one. For the projection theorem to apply in a Hilbert space.

Comment: @julien you are absolutely right. And it would be a good hint for the proof of uniqueness.

Comment: I know that is hilbert and so inner product, but I do not know how to find best approximation. Please help me

Comment: @Hakhak if $f\notin k$, what would be the best approximation of $f$ from set $k$? Is it the one given in the very first comment?